# php7.0 curl.so takes process memory more then 150mb

Tags: php, curl, memory-leaks, file-get-contents

I am using curl to get web page. when i run it on cli ubuntu process takes 191mb. But with file_get_contents process size with same page is in kb's.

I tried to run php with -n option and add dl('curl.so') in code. just after adding curl.so in code process memory increase to 191mb. without calling curl function.

Does any one knows why process is taking so much of memory when using curl in php7.0?